# javax.mail.MessagingException -Sending Mail Background

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-service, background-process

please help how to solve this problem. here i refer many links. but my problem not solved. i know many of them ask same question here. i try lot of time but not working. Gmail using send mail working. but me want other domail use sending mail. following error will be displayed in logcat

```
     javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: trucksoft.net, port: 25;

        javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed



my source code here


public class GmailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
    private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";
    private String user;
    private String password;
    private Session session;

    static {
        Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());
    }

    public GmailSender(String user, String password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;

         Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "trucksoft.net");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.debug", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", 25);
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", 25);
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");




        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
    }

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body,
            String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {
        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(
                    body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
            message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setDataHandler(handler);
            if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
            else
                message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        new InternetAddress(recipients));
            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
Log.e("exec", ""+e.toString());
        }
    }

    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {
        private byte[] data;
        private String type;

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
            this.type = type;
        }

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
        }

        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String getContentType() {
            if (type == null)
                return "application/octet-stream";
            else
                return type;
        }

        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return "ByteArrayDataSource";
        }

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
            throw new IOException("Not Supported");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that I've used to solve the same problem:

```
public void sendEmail(){
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.sasl.enable", "false");
Session session = Session.getInstance(props);

final URLName unusedUrlName = null;
SMTPTransport transport = new SMTPTransport(session, unusedUrlName);
final String emptyPassword = null;
transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, "username@gmail.com", emptyPassword);
// you can get the access token when you do Auth2 for gmail, I haven't tried this with just a password
byte[] response = String.format("user=%s\1auth=Bearer %s\1\1", "username@gmail.com", accessToken).getBytes();
response = BASE64EncoderStream.encode(response);
transport.issueCommand("AUTH XOAUTH2 " + new String(response), 235);


Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
//add needed stuff to the message before sending it. 

transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
transport.close();
```

}